# How to put tweets in avro files and save them in HDFS using Spring XD?

Tags: avro, spring-xd

how can I put tweets in avro files and save them in HDFS using Spring XD? The docu only tells me to do the following:

```
xd:>stream create --name mydataset --definition "time | hdfs-dataset --batchSize=20" --deploy
```

This works fine for the source "time" but if I want to store tweets as avro it only puts the raw json Strings in the avro files, which is pretty dumb.

I could not find any detailed information about how to tell Spring XD to apply a specific Avro Schema (avsc) or convert the json String to Tweet object.

Do I have to build a custom converter?

Can somebody please help? This is driving me insane...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [hdfs-dataset documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M6/reference/html/#hdfs-dataset-avroparquet), Kite SDK is used to infer the AVRO schema based on the object you passed into it.  From its perspective, you passed in a String, which is why it behaves as it does.  Since there is no mechanism to explicitly pick a schema for hdfs-dataset to use, you'll have to create a Java Class representative of the tweet (or use the Twitter4J api), turn the tweet JSON into a Java object (a custom processor will be necessary), and output that to your sink.  Hdfs-dataset will use a schema based on your class.